# Socket.io Client connects, socket.on events don't fire

Tags: javascript, sockets

I'm using the package "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0"

In my web app I have the following code on bootstrap:

```
export const socket = io.connect(process.env.VUE_APP_SOCKET_URL, {
  reconnection: true,
  reconnectionDelay: 1000,
  reconnectionDelayMax: 5000,
  reconnectionAttempts: Infinity
})
```

Then later in the app cycle I have the following listener

```
import socket from './api/socket'

function handleAutobox() {
  console.log('handling autobox')
}
console.log('Connect')
socket.on('autobox', handleAutobox)
```

When inspecting in production, I see that the code has run ('Connect' is logged). I see that the socket network traffic is captured:

[image]

The problem is the `handleAutobox` function is never called. If I'm sure I've run socket.on, how is that possible?

**UPDATE: ADDING SERVER SIDE CODE:**

```
let socket_io = require('socket.io'),
    io;

let server = http.createServer(app)
  .listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    io = socket_io.listen(server);
    console.info(`App listening on port ${port}!`);
  });

// ...inside route function:
io.emit('autobox', autobox);
```

**UPDATE: ADDING `socket.on('connect' ...)`:**

When adding `socket.on('connect' ...)` directly after creating the socket, I am finding that doesn't get called either. Instead of `io.connect(...)` I tried @Keith's suggestion of `io()` with separate `io.on` events, still no dice.

So the real problem is that no "connection" is being made but data is still being sent on the network. I guess I'm really not understanding something about sockets. Apparently data can be sent even though no connection is established?

Comment: Curiously this only happens in production. In my development environment, everything works just fine.

Comment: Have you tried `io.on('autobox'...`, as the socket returned from `io.connect` I think is the physical socket, and not socket.io's, handler..

Comment: `io.on` is not a function as imported like so: `import io from 'socket.io-client'`

Comment: Well I normally create an instance.. `const socket = io(); socket.on("cmd",...`  and then we have the function `on`...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `console.log('Connect')` is global so it will run no matter what. try putting it in your a function that calls when socket is connected. so on your server do you have  something like

```js
io.on('connection' function(socket) {
  console.log('Socket Connected');
// Update
io.emit('autobox', autobox);
  socket.emit('autobox');
})
```

U can not place socket code inside of routes it has to be inside this connection callback and this callback only. At least thats what I have been told. Hope this helps

Comment: I added the `console.log('Connect')` simply to show that the `socket.on` had run. I guess it would be better written, `console.log('socket.on ran')`. But if the network shows the frames coming through and `socket.on` ran, why wouldn't it trigger the event?

Comment: According to this documentation https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98connect%E2%80%99 `you should register event handlers outside of connect`. And as noted before, the network shows I'm receiving data... is that not proof I'm connected?

Comment: Please post your server side code regarding socket.io

Comment: @jbodily  Yeah, I'm thinking serverside,

Comment: @djorborn - I think you'll find it pretty trivial. I'm not doing anything fancy other than sending down the autobox, which is what you see in the network picture included in the question. Odd because this works in development.

Comment: It looks like you are missing your connection callback function. you need to have `// ...inside route function:
io.emit('autobox', autobox);` inside of io.on('connection', function (socket){//here})

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding something about sockets. If the network shows the data going across it, could it be a connection issue? It seems to me that the server and the client are connected and talking just fine. Or does it send data without being connected?

Comment: web sockets are different then a regular http connection. When you use sockets you are upgrading the connection from http to socket and then the connection stays open instead of its normal function of closing. There are no urls or routes for sockets, tools like socket.io add layers of abstraction to make it all much more simple and add functionality. For information about socket.io in your use case check this link out. https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Node-http-server . hope it helps. good luck